Can Einstein's reasons for believing in Spinoza's God be structured as a deductive or syllogistic argument?
I'll start with a few quotes from Religious and philosophical views of Albert Einstein - Wikipedia:

Albert Einstein's religious views have been widely studied and often misunderstood. Albert Einstein stated "I believe in Spinoza's God". He did not believe in a personal God who concerns himself with fates and actions of human beings, a view which he described as naïve. He clarified, however, that, "I am not an atheist", preferring to call himself an agnostic, or a "religious nonbeliever." In other interviews, he stated that he thought that there is a "lawgiver" who sets the laws of the universe. Einstein also stated he did not believe in life after death, adding "one life is enough for me." He was closely involved in his lifetime with several humanist groups. Einstein rejected a conflict between science and religion, and held that cosmic religion was necessary for science.


Albert Einstein himself stated "I'm not an atheist, and I don't think I can call myself a pantheist ... I believe in Spinoza's God who reveals himself in the orderly harmony of what exists, not in a God who concerns himself with fates and actions of human beings". Einstein believed the problem of God was the "most difficult in the world"—a question that could not be answered "simply with yes or no". He conceded that "the problem involved is too vast for our limited minds".


Pantheism and Spinoza's God
Einstein had explored the idea that humans could not understand the nature of God. In an interview published in George Sylvester Viereck's book Glimpses of the Great (1930), Einstein responded to a question about whether or not he defined himself as a pantheist. He explained:

Your question is the most difficult in the world. It is not a question I can answer simply with yes or no. I am not an Atheist. I do not know if I can define myself as a Pantheist. The problem involved is too vast for our limited minds. May I not reply with a parable? The human mind, no matter how highly trained, cannot grasp the universe. We are in the position of a little child, entering a huge library whose walls are covered to the ceiling with books in many different tongues. The child knows that someone must have written those books. It does not know who or how. It does not understand the languages in which they are written. The child notes a definite plan in the arrangement of the books, a mysterious order, which it does not comprehend, but only dimly suspects. That, it seems to me, is the attitude of the human mind, even the greatest and most cultured, toward God. We see a universe marvelously arranged, obeying certain laws, but we understand the laws only dimly. Our limited minds cannot grasp the mysterious force that sways the constellations. I am fascinated by Spinoza's Pantheism. I admire even more his contributions to modern thought. Spinoza is the greatest of modern philosophers, because he is the first philosopher who deals with the soul and the body as one, not as two separate things.



Einstein said people could call him an agnostic rather than an atheist, stating: "I have repeatedly said that in my opinion the idea of a personal god is a childlike one. You may call me an agnostic, but I do not share the crusading spirit of the professional atheist whose fervor is mostly due to a painful act of liberation from the fetters of religious indoctrination received in youth. I prefer an attitude of humility corresponding to the weakness of our intellectual understanding of nature and of our own being." In an interview published by the German poet George Sylvester Viereck, Einstein stated, "I am not an Atheist." According to Prince Hubertus, Einstein said, "In view of such harmony in the cosmos which I, with my limited human mind, am able to recognize, there are yet people who say there is no God. But what really makes me angry is that they quote me for the support of such views."

It seems to me that Einstein admired the order of the universe, which can be elegantly captured in mathematical equations, and from this, he inferred the existence of a Spinozan God behind it all.
First, am I understanding Einstein's perspective correctly? Second, is there a way to present Einstein's argument for Spinoza's God more formally, perhaps as a deductive argument or syllogism?

It is not a deductive argument:"We  see a universe marvelously arranged, obeying certain laws, but we understand the laws only dimly. Our limited minds cannot grasp the mysterious force that sways the constellations." It is intelligent design "axiom".

@MauroALLEGRANZA Are you saying that Einstein had no reasons for believing in Spinoza's God, that his belief was entirely axiomatic? His reasoning faculties were not involved in the matter?

An axiom is not necessarily a trivial and obvious assertion. "The speed of light is an universal constant" was not trivial and obvious at all.

The same for what I've called the ID axiom: "If we perceive order, there is some ordering intelligence". It is not trivial, and presumably false.

No, Einstein's argument cannot be structured deductively because it is explicitly an induction followed by an abduction. He surmises a "universe marvelously arranged, obeying certain laws" (induction) and infers the "mysterious force that sways the constellations" (abduction). Spinoza's God/Nature is deemed to be the best candidate for such a force, hence the inference. By the way, Spinoza is a very unusual kind of pantheist, if he is a pantheist at all, as he does not support religious reverence before God/Nature, see SEP.

Much ink has been spilled about Einstein’s words, those which are authentic but detached from their context and those which are only ascribed to him.

Concerning the OP’s post I do not understand what the great man
means.  On one hand, Einstein says

“The human mind, no matter how highly trained, cannot grasp the
universe.”

That’s easy to understand and shows its truth for every working
scientist or philosopher of nature.
On the other hand, Einstein
speculates with a metaphor that someone behind created the universe.
That’s what @Mauro rightly characterizes as a form of intelligent
design, which I cannot consider a compliment for an eminent
scientist like Einstein.

Hiding behind Spinoza's pantheism does not clarify one’s own position.
Instead, introducing pantheism into a discussion adds further difficulties
because the meaning and the use of the equality “universe = God” is not well
understood. See also the previous post pantheism - atheism.


I don’t see that Einstein presents any argument for his metaphor. And it is futile to attempt a formalization of a metaphor if the basic concept is as problematic as the concept of pantheism.

Downvoters should say something.

From the same Wikipedia Article, I extracted most of the references I could find to his statements and writings made later in his life.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_and_philosophical_views_of_Albert_Einstein

In a 1947 letter he stated that "It seems to me that the idea of a personal God is an anthropological concept which I cannot take seriously."

In a letter to Beatrice Frohlich on 17 December 1952, Einstein stated, "The idea of a personal God is quite alien to me and seems even naïve."

On January 3, 1954, Einstein sent the following reply to Gutkind: "The word God is for me nothing more than the expression and product of human weaknesses, the Bible a collection of honourable, but still primitive legends which are nevertheless pretty childish. .... For me the Jewish religion like all other religions is an incarnation of the most childish superstitions."

Einstein replied on 24 March 1954. to a letter from a fan who was concerned by people saying "Einstein believes in a god".  Einstein wrote... "It was, of course, a lie what you read about my religious convictions, a lie which is being systematically repeated. I do not believe in a personal God and I have never denied this but have expressed it clearly. If something is in me which can be called religious then it is the unbounded admiration for the structure of the world so far as our science can reveal it."

In his book Ideas and Opinions (1954) Einstein stated, "In their struggle for the ethical good, teachers of religion must have the stature to give up the doctrine of a personal God, that is, give up that source of fear and hope which in the past placed such vast power in the hands of priests."

On 17 July 1953 a woman who was a licensed Baptist pastor sent Einstein a letter asking if he had felt assured about attaining everlasting life with the Creator. Einstein replied, "I do not believe in immortality of the individual, and I consider ethics to be an exclusively human concern with no superhuman authority behind it."



If someone was going to speak for you an a subject, would you want them to represent your current opinion, or pick and choose among old things you said, to make is seem like you have a different opinion?
Doesn't it make the most sense to put the most weight on the things Einstein said later in his life?
If one is going to put any weight at all on Einstein's opinions on the subject.  They are opinions, not fact, not knowledge, not information... opinions... I think at least use his later opinions.

This completely fails to answer the question. None of your quotes contradicts the fact that Einstein believed in Spinoza's God, which is NOT the same conception of God as the one your quotes are referring to (video 1, video 2, video 3)

I think you completely missed my point... what Einstein said about gods in 1930 gets cancelled out by later statements that show his more considered thoughts on the subject.... To claim Einstein "believed in gods" in the 1950s... is like saying "Einstein believed in Santa Claus" because he wrote that he did when he was 5 years old.  It is not logical.

This is a textbook example of the equivocation fallacy. Spinoza's God is NOT the same conception of God as traditional monotheism. There are A and B. Your entire answer is about ranting against B. My question is about A. This answer is pure equivocation and misses completely the point. Moreover, if you really think Einstein didn't believe in Spinoza's God, you should immediately go ahead and edit the Wikipedia article on Einstein's beliefs to fix the error ASAP. You will make a significant contribution to the knowledge of humanity.

I did not, nor do not deny that Einstein said some things on the subjects of religions and gods that seemed supportive of such notions... IN 1930.  I said... to understand "Einstein's views"... we need first hear his last thoughts, then consider backwards through time, his earlier thoughts and opinions.  To present 1930 thoughts as "Einstein's thoughts" is dishonest.  To present them as "thoughts he held in 1930, which may have later changed" would be a more honest representation of things like "I believe in a Spinoza's God"... sure... in 1930.  So what?

Go ahead and edit the Wikipedia article. And send an email to Michio Kaku to correct his views on Einstein.

Moreover, this still fails to answer the question, because even if you go ahead and edit the Wikipedia article and everyone in the world officially agrees that you are right, you are still conceding that Einstein claimed to believe in Spinoza's God in 1930, and  so the question is still valid with respect to what Einstein said in 1930. "Can Einstein's reasoning in 1930 be formalized?" is a perfectly valid question which you are failing to answer.

+1 for your overview of some further Einstein statements which seem to be authentic. - ad @user80226: Why do you start such a harsh attack on the above answer and its author?

@JoWehler Because it doesn't answer the question. Read the comments.

@JoWehler Thanks.  It seems naturally logical to me, if we are going to draw conclusions about a dead individuals "beliefs"... we start with the last things he said on the subject, not what he said when he was younger, less informed, and had less time to think on the subject..

@JoWehler and Alistair, check this out: https://www.magiscenter.com/blog/did-einstein-believe-god

@user80226 Why?  It is desperation.  It brings up the content of a letter Einstein wrote to a little schoolgirl.  Nobody is going to be blunt to a little schoolgirl, so his words will be careful, and non-oppressive.  As one would speak to a schoolgirl.  Why it is included in an exploration of his supposed thoughts on the matter... reveals it is a biased article with an agenda, not a legitimate investigation into his thoughts.

@user80226 I agree with OP. This is not remotely an answer. (a) It conflates (equivocates) pantheism with theism. Is a pineapple an apple? Maybe an apple that  grows on pine trees?  In particular when the name of Spinoza comes in one needs to be even more careful. Spinoza has been called God-mad as much as he's been called atheist. In any case he was lifelong excommunicated for heresy.  So if the Sanhedrin of the personal-god religions give him the boot there is no disagreement with a 4 centuries later Enistein saying Im not an atheist plus Personal god religions are childish

(b) Even more to the point: The question asks about structured as a syllogism or deductive logic. Either you give that or you give a refutation of the request viz. that such a request is not possible. All you've given is the credo of your religion

@Rushi within the question, Einstein is credited with saying "The problem involved is too vast for our limited minds. May I not reply with a parable? The human mind, no matter how highly trained, cannot grasp the universe".  If he were able to create a "syllogism structured logic"... then it would not be ungraspable... it would be grasped.

Im not sure how your above comment helps your case; it seems to go against you AFAIK. Your preferred quote is for agnosticism. OP's request is for pantheism. Are you claiming that pantheism and agnosticism are mutually inconsistent? [See my pineapple above] You seem stuck on a very bizarre point that somehow Einstein in 1930s was immature compared to 1950s. In the 30s, Einstein would be 50 years old!!! Dont you see thats a stretch from a 5 year old Santa Claus? In fact history is that Einstein was rather a stubborn guy wrt his known-to-be-wrong views — see his intransigence re quantum physics

@Rushi showing that he claims we cannot know contradicts the notion that his "belief in Spinoza's God" can by be arrived at by logical reasoning.  Does it not?

Umm... ok If you read it in that literal way, I accept. But Spinoza's God is not God (in the usual Judeo Christian sense), just as a pineapple is not an apple. Spinoza language is very very bizarre and should be carefully translated to 'normalese' before interpreting.  Spinozas 'God' is much closer to normal persons 'nature' than to normal persons 'God'

Yes... Spinoza's "God" does seem like a bait and switch, and not like a god at all.  It could be called "Spinoza's nonGod" and still have the same parameters and characteristics.
